# recvfrom is not receiving any data, but client is sending the message successfully

Tags: c, sockets, sctp

I have client-server program where I created the socket with sctp protocol and client and server has a onetomany relation.

when I run the client code the return value of sendto function is greater than zero. But I don't see any message in the server code output.

Even when the server code is not running and only the client code is running, the client code shows successful message sent. How can it be when the server sockeet is not even open?

```
/*
 * Compile:
 *
 *   gcc sctp.c -o server -lsctp
 *
 * Invoke:
 *
 *   ./client
 *   ./server
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/sctp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MY_PORT_NUM 21233

static void die(const char *s) {
        perror(s);
        exit(1);
}

static void server(void) {
        int listen_fd, conn_fd, flags, ret, in;
        struct sctp_sndrcvinfo sndrcvinfo;
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr = {
                .sin_family = AF_INET,
                .sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY),
                .sin_port = htons(MY_PORT_NUM),
        };
        struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
        socklen_t clilen=sizeof(client_addr);
        struct sctp_initmsg initmsg = {
                .sinit_num_ostreams = 5,
                .sinit_max_instreams = 5,
                .sinit_max_attempts = 4,
        };

        listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_SEQPACKET, IPPROTO_SCTP);
        if (listen_fd < 0)
                die("socket");

        ret = bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
        if (ret < 0)
                die("bind");


        ret = listen(listen_fd, initmsg.sinit_max_instreams);
        if (ret < 0)
                die("listen");

        for (;;) {
                char buffer[1024];

                printf("Waiting for connection\n");

                in = recvfrom(listen_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&clilen);
                printf("%d\n",in);
                    if (in > 0) {
                            printf("Received data: %s\n", buffer);
                            fflush(stdout);
                    }
                sleep(2);

                
        }
        close(listen_fd);
}

static void client(void) {
        int conn_fd, ret;
        const char *msg = "Hello, Server!";
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr = {
                .sin_family = AF_INET,
                .sin_port = htons(MY_PORT_NUM),
                .sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"),
        };

        conn_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_SEQPACKET, IPPROTO_SCTP);
        if (conn_fd < 0)
                die("socket()");
            
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            printf("before sending\n");
            ret = sendto(conn_fd, (void *) msg, strlen(msg) + 1,0,(struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
            printf("after sending\n");
            if (ret < 0)
                    printf("failed to send %d\n",i);
            else 
                printf("success %d\n",i);
            
            sleep(2);
            
        }
        close(conn_fd);
        
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        if (strstr(basename(argv[0]), "server"))
                server();
        else
                client();

        return 0;
}
```

this code works when I run the client and server in same machine with loopback IP 127.0.0.1 but when I run them on two different remote machines I am facing this issue.

Comment: Rather than run your server and client together, both of which may be buggy, run a known-good client with your server and vice versa.  I like to use `nc` (netcat) for this, and I think it will work in your case.

Comment: does netcat support sctp protocol?

Comment: regarding: `sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY),`  I have been told that `INADDR_ANY` is already in the network format, so should no be passed through `htonl()`

Comment: regarding: `in = recvfrom(listen_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&clilen);
                printf("%d\n",in);
                    if (in > 0) {
                            printf("Received data: %s\n", buffer);`  The function: `recvfrom()` does not NUL terminate the data, so the code should be: `in = recvfrom(listen_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&clilen);
                printf("%d\n",in);
                    if (in > 0) {  buffer[ in ] = '\0';
                            printf("Received data: %s\n", buffer);`

Comment: regarding: `in = recvfrom(listen_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&clilen);`  This leaves no room in `buffer` if the sender sends a full message, so the statement should be: `in = recvfrom( listen_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&clilen );` so there is room to insert a trailing NUL byte

Comment: regarding: `ret = sendto(conn_fd, (void *) msg, strlen(msg) + 1,0,(struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
            printf("after sending\n");
            if (ret < 0)
                    printf("failed to send %d\n",i);`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  and when the error is from a c library function should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  (note: the function: `printf()` changes `errno`)  the function: `perror()` is made for this purpose.

Comment: when the returned value from: `sendto()` is 0, that means the other end of the connection closed the connection.  The code should be checking for that condition.

Comment: regarding; ` .sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"),`  when run on different machines, this IP address will NOT work.

Comment: thank you for your comments but does not help me at all. I said that this code runs in local machine with loop back address. when I run it in remote machine it does not work. and yes I have change  inet_addr("127.0.0.1"), this with the IP of the remote machine

Comment: Your server is calling `listen()`, but it is not calling `accept()` on the listen fd.